# Get all the tags except the first tags using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have html structure like this:

```
<table><tr><p>Hello1</p></tr><tr><p>Shirt</p></tr></table>
<table><tr><p>Hello2</p></tr><tr><p>Jeans</p></tr><tr><p>Jacket</p></tr></table>
<table><tr><p>Hello3</p></tr><tr><p>Trouser</p></tr></table>
```

I to get all the `tr` tags in all tables except the first `tr` tag in every table.

Output should be like:

```
Shirt
Jeans
Jacket
Trouser
```

My current code is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
n = soup.findAll('table')

for tr in n:
    t = tr.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('span')
    for p in t:
        print(p.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code above is that you are only getting the second `tr` with the `[1]` index.  Instead, what you want to use is a splice `[1:]`, which gets everything after the first.  Also, to get the text, use `find(text=True)` instead of getting the span. See below for the solution:

```
import BeautifulSoup
n = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
for table in n.findAll('table'):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        print tr.find(text=True)
```

*Note:* the above prints objects on a newline, whereas your ouput suggested they should be on a separate line. That should be a trivial change.